# Parse error in plist when I add associated-domains key into Entitlement.plist

Tags: ios, xamarin, plist, deep-linking

I'm using xamarin to build an application and I need to add my domains into Entitlement.plist for allowing me to have deep links, but when delivering app to Apple's app store, the deliver fails with a message like "parse error in plist: ."

This is my Entitlement.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    
    <!--facebook needed-->
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>X0XX000XXX.com.Bundle</string>
    </array>
    <!--end facebook needed-->

    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:domain.com</string>
        <string>applinks:www.domain.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I remove the key com.apple.developer.associated-domains and its array, everything works fine again.  What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This probably was due to no provisioning license found. Created apple developer account and setup app id and provisioning profile. In Xcode you had to download the profile too. Then you have to match the bundle identifier to the app id and assigned the identity too.

More information you can refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/entitlements?tabs=windows